# Intel processor has 8 threads but only showing 4 in task manager

Tags: windows-server-2008, virtualization, intel

I have a server with an Intel Xeon E3-1240 3.3Ghz processor. According to intel's website this processor has 4 cores and 8 threads, however in Windows Task Manager there are only 4 showing.

The server has Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard.

Why would there only be 4 threads when it is listed by intel as having 8?

This is the processor:
http://ark.intel.com/products/52273/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E3-1240-8M-Cache-3_30-GHz

Comment: I'd just check your BIOS version is up to date, that Hyperthreading is enabled in BIOS and that your Windows Updates are good.

Comment: The # of Threads refers to Hyperthreading. Is Hyperthreading enabled?

Comment: There was a bios setting which was not enabled - have changed it and there are now 8 threads/cores in the task manager. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

I think you are confused by the Task Manager. Task Manager is showing you cores, therefore it is right as your processor has 4 cores.